# Repeat each cell in a spill range by corresponding multiplier in second spill range

Tags: excel, dynamic-arrays, excel-365

[image]

How can I create a dynamic formula that will take the spill range in A4# and repeat each text value by the multiplier value in the corresponding row of the spill range B4#?

I am not looking for a VBA solution.